# How to update the probabilities so that it still sum up to $1$?

Tags: probability, special-functions

At time $t$, I have a probability vector $\mathbf{\pi}^{t}=\left({\pi}_{1}^{t}, \cdots, {\pi}_{n}^{t} \right)$.

I would like to construct a function $f(\cdot)$ and update the vector $\mathbf{\pi}^{t+1}$ at time $t+1$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(\mathbf{\pi}_{i}^{t}\right)=1.$$

One way to do this is as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{\pi}_{i_0}^{t+1}=\mathbf{\pi}_{i_0}^{t}+\tau\cdot(1-\mathbf{\pi}_{i_0}^{t}),i_0\in\{1, \cdots, n\}\\
\mathbf{\pi}_{i}^{t+1}=\mathbf{\pi}_{i}^{t}-\tau\cdot\mathbf{\pi}_{i}^{t},\,\forall\;i\in\{1, \cdots, n\}\backslash\{i_0\}
\end{cases}.
$$
The above update rule can be interpreted as: *increment the probability of the winning event $i_0$ and decrease the probabilities of all other events*.

In the case where there is no winning event, how to construct the function $f(\cdot)$? And in general, how to get such function?

Maybe the question appears too board, but I would like to get some hints from you. I appreciate your helps.

Comment: I am afraid there is no question here.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear enough @Did. I have an agent which has $n$ choices (say), I would like to update the belief of this agent (probabilities) after taking some action (choices). If this agent is happy after an action has been taken, I increase the probability of this action and decrease the others (as I wrote above). I would like to get another update rule when there is no winning action (the agent not happy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the easiest way to do this is 
$$
f(\pi_k)=\frac{\pi_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \pi_k}
$$
another one:
$$
f(\pi_k) = \frac{e^{-\pi_k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{-\pi_k}}
$$

Comment: It seems for me that a more correct way is intiruduce a stochastic (transition, Marcov) matrix $P$, such that $\pi^{t+1}=P_t \pi_t$. Then $\pi^{t+1}$ automatically will be the updated vector of probabilities satisfying $\sum \pi^{t+1}_i=1$

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand each suggestion. The first function is the identity. In the second case, the RHS is not a function of $\pi_k$ only but of the whole vector $(\pi_i)$.

Comment: This is how I understood the question.